# php doesn't throw an error but just a notice when i access an undefined property of an object/array

Tags: php, json

so javascript (ajax) sends a stringified JSON object to php which gets json_decoded and then i reference the properties of the object in order to save them in the database.

```
$Name = $Person->Name;
$Surname = $Person->Surname;
```

Now the client could be malicious and it could have renamed some of the Person property names before sending the JSON to the server and I would like to avoid this condition.

So the client could have renamed the "Name" property to "Name555", so when i try to get $Person->Name **I thought** it would throw and error but unfortunately it doesn't instead I get back to the client just a notice about:

```
Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$Name in /home/aaa/public_html/saveperson.php on line 38
```

Is there any non-hacky way to make php throw an error in such cases? Or any general way of solving the problem in server-side (preferrably non-hacky, maybe some php.cnf configuration or something?).

thank you in advance.

Comment: you can try with try catch, place the error return in catch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It already throws an error. If you are determined to immediately act upon it you can install a custom error handler with [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php).

That said, this is not the PHP way (or any language's way really) to check incoming data. A robust application would actively check that the input is valid and do something if it's not. In this instance you would do that with:

```
if (!isset($Person->Name)) {
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: I would like to avoid isset()-ing all 20 properties, because this might cause a performance issue especially with many users, that's why i thought an error throwing solution would be better than having 20 issset() in the code. maybe i'm wrong and isset() is does not have a heavy penalty, will make a benchmark.

Comment: @MIrrorMirror: You don't ever write 20 calls to the same function. Write a loop that iterates 20 times instead. Or convert to array instead of object and use a simple array addition or `array_merge_recursive` (depending on what structure the data is expected to have) to populate everything with "empty" values (which you have to deal with anyway). There are lots of options, the best choice depends on the specifics.

Comment: thank you for your comment. I'm not sure I got what you meant by saying no need for 20 calls of isset. If the object has 20 properties ( surname, firstname, age etc.), wouldn't I need to !isset(person->surname) || !isset(person->firstname etc etc which would amount to 20 calls?

Comment: @MIrrorMirror: You 'd make an array with the names of the 20 properties and then run a loop: `foreach ($properties as $name) if (!isset($Person->$property)) ...`.

Comment: ah i got it now, but still it's 20 calls, i didn't have a problem with manual typing, but with the probable performance hit caused by it

Comment: @MIrrorMirror: I don't see why you should worry about that unless you are Twitter.

Comment: FYI: You can check all 20 properties with 1 [isset](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) call.

Answer (score 1):

My try/catch statement was wrong, but with

```
if(!isset(@Person->Name)){ throw new Exception... }
```

should work.

Comment: `isset` will not throw an exception, it'll just return `FALSE` if the property doesn't exist.

Comment: as @GeorgeMarques points out this won't generate an exception so try won't catch anything. You can however do: `if(!isset(@Person->Name)){ throw new Exception... }`

Comment: Thanks you guys, reading the source I assumed the statement in the `try` block needed only to return false to trip the `catch` block.